# How do I change a replace a single word within a text file?

Tags: shell

Say I had a file called `name.txt` with the following:

```
white-list=true
max-players=3
motd=Welcome // Version: One
```

How would I go about finding the world `One` and only replacing this world with `Two` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed 's/One/Two/1'` to replace one occurrence of One with Two (replace '1' with 'g' to replace every occurrence of One).

```
# Note the /1 makes the One to Two happen once.
echo "Welcome // Version: One" | sed 's/One/Two/1'
```

So, for a file "name.txt" you could do

```
cat "name.txt" | sed 's/One/Two/1' > "temp.name.txt" && mv "temp.name.txt" "name.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the answer by Elliot Frisch, some versions of `sed` have a `-i` option to change "in place" (in fact, `sed` itself create the temporary file for you)

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```
>
> <sub>from `man sed` (GNU sed version 4.2.1)</sub>

So you could simplify use the command:

```
sed -i 's/One/Two/' name.txt
```

or

```
sed -i 's/One/Two/g' name.txt
```